# Quicker way to reach all communities from your own user profile

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, communities-list

As of now, this is what I see in Chrome on my Android 10,

[image]

Regularly I'm in one community analyzing the profile and would like to quickly navigate to the profile in another community. I can do that from the profile but only to the communities where I have the highest reputation.

Could we add an hyperlink to "Communities" or a "View all Communities" near the edit or in the bottom of the communities list?

This would make the experience more natural than the approach I currently use -> go to the top right hamburger menu and click in "Your Communities".

[image]

---

Note: the same happens in Desktop mode, the Communities section only has "edit"

[image]

Comment: If you look at someone else’s profile, there is indeed a “View all” link. For some reason it’s missing (replaced with the “Edit” button) when you look at your own profile.

Comment: Re *"the top right hamburger menu"*: That is the Stack Exchange *logo* (derived from the tilting Stack Overflow logo?), not a hamburger menu (though it is some kind of menu).

Comment: There used to be such link, I'm almost sure, and they removed it.

Answer (score 5):

While [there is a one click way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372427/152859), here is another way just in case the other way disappears again. Two-click way to see all your accounts when you're already in the profile page:

1. Click "Network profile":
   [image: Network profile link]
2. Click "accounts" tab:
   [image: accounts tab in network profile]

Profit.

Comment: upvoted for the attempt at a freehand red circle.

Comment: @Luuklag hey! That's free hand red Smiley! :D

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres no, your question is clearly **"from your own user profile"** so it's two clicks. If you meant reach it from anywhere, that's **different question**. Feel free to edit your question, and I'll delete my answer as it won't be relevant anymore.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 you're right!

Comment: Another option, apart from the one mentioned in the question and in this answer, is clicking in "View all network posts" on the right of _Top network posts_ (which is also a two click approach)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres yeah, but see new answer, turns out we missed something all along, lol.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how I didn't notice before (or I did but it was gone for a while), when in the [activity tab of the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) (which happens to also be the default), there is an *Accounts* section with a "View all" link:

[image: View all link in Account section]

One click travel to the list of all accounts. :)

Comment: That's still a two click from profile though

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres how? Clicking own profile leads to activity tab, and it is there. No?

Comment: The “Accounts” section is very well hidden. Unlike all the other sections, there is no link to it from the left side-bar (this is probably a bug), hence one has to scroll down and down and down and down to find it serendipitously.